# Interstellar pioneers that evolve according to planet

Tags: story-identification, space-colonization, evolution

A library book that I read in the 1990s so Could be older, about different single pioneers sent to different planets and they each adapted to the environment of that planet. The main character grew one really big arm with claws. Think it was a series

Comment: Larry Niven does this a lot in the Known Space universe, but I can’t think of any clawed humans.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Sounds like a partial match to: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166801/man-undergoes-radical-surgery-to-research-aliens I don't remember a transformation with a big arm with claws.